# How to retain special character in DB while importing from a script

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using a database script file `import.sql`. This file contains database table data. Say one value is `my-name`, but when I import this file into MySQL database, I got `myÃ¢â‚¬â„¢ve name`. I am not getting how to get special char as it is. Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be encoding issue. Make your database connection UTF-8 encoded(jdbc:mysql://localhost/some_db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8). Also make the table/column UTF-8 encoded in which this data is being stored. And if you are importing files using java servlet, then you have to encode the imported content with UTF-8. Because java servlet apply default encoding to it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I used "?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" i hibernate config. but still the prob is same. am using import.sql to import data in mysql database. and its in my classpath. am not getting how to make table utf-8

Comment: I have looked into it. am using MySQl query browser, and i can see here created DB that is being created by code not manually(using hibernate), so how to change , if its not utf-8.

Comment: Execute ALTER table query like this: ALTER TABLE t MODIFY latin1_text_col TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY latin1_varchar_col VARCHAR(M) CHARACTER SET utf8;

Comment: Oh buddy, i have done all this. but it will be at my local m/c. i need to do it on server too. is thr any way to do it via configuration.

Comment: I don't know exactly, but you can execute this query after you server starts up using pure JDBC connection. Catch server start up event and execute this query

Comment: Have you tried sending a `SET NAMES UTF8` query before your `INSERT` statements?

Comment: when i used Set Names UTF8 , i got java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\x96 US' for column 'name' exception :(